# Which Nuget version to use for a package released today

Tags: nuget

i release an assembly in form of a nuget packet. i can choose between nuget commandline version 1.4, 1.5 (3 versions) or 1.6. which version should one use?

Comment: thx, did that. in the end, teamcity offered all these versions but download was possible only of the 1.6 anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally always use the latest version (run `nuget.exe update -self` to make sure you're up-to-date). With every new release of NuGet, we ensure that packages built using an older version still work.

Comment: oh, an answer right out of the kitchen, thx! My concern was that maybe many people out there do not have the latest version and if I as a publisher publish a too new version, they cannot use it without upgrading their package manager before. what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: It's possible that can happen, but we very rarely have seen this be an issue. NuGet shows a message when there is a new version, so folks tend to keep up-to-date. And, even then it would only matter if your package used a new feature introduced in the later version. And even some of those would just be ignored by the older client.